# How to use int and double type?

Tags: c++, int, double

The Question
[image]

I want to know what went wrong with my code. It keeps showing `2.42092e-322` as result after the calculation. I thought it was because I use `int calcFee` so I changed it to `double calcFee` but it still shows the same result. Can you guys point out what went wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void detail();
double calcFee();
int main()
{
    double total_fee;
    detail();
    total_fee = calcFee();

    cout << "The total fee is RM " << total_fee << endl;
    return 0;
}

void detail()
{
    cout << "\t\t___________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|  Participant Category\t|\tParticipant Type\t|    Fee per Member(RM)   |" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|_______________________|_______________________________|_________________________|" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|\t    S\t\t|\t\t1\t\t|\t   50.00\t  |" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|\t\t\t|_______________________________|_________________________|" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|\t\t\t|\t\t2\t\t|\t   75.00\t  |" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|_______________________|_______________________________|_________________________|" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|\t    T\t\t|\t\t1\t\t|\t  100.00\t  |" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|\t\t\t|_______________________________|_________________________|" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|\t\t\t|\t\t2\t\t|\t  150.00\t  |" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t|_______________________|_______________________________|_________________________|" << endl;
}

double calcFee()
{
    double total_fee = 0, member;
    char category;
    int type;
    cout << endl << "Enter your category (S/T): ";
    cin >> category;
    cout << "Enter your type (1/2): ";
    cin >> type;
    cout << "Enter number of participants: ";
    cin >> member;
    if(category == 'S' || category == 's')
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    total_fee = 50.00 * member;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                {
                    total_fee = 75.00 * member;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    else if(category == 'T' || category == 't')
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    total_fee = 100.00 * member;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                {
                    total_fee = 150.00 * member;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return total_fee;
}
```

Thanks to those who helped me. I'll make sure to make good use of your tips and lessons

Comment: You never assign anything to that variable in main.

Comment: `total_fee` is uninitialized, hence printing it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Giving things the same name does not make them the same thing. (And you shouldn't use parameters as local variables.)

Comment: See `std::tolower` and `std::toupper` so you only need one comparison for letters.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews : Except the question states that the input is always `S` or `T`, so there is no need to test lower-case at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the return value of `calcFee()` to the `main()` local variable `total_fee`:

```
total_fee = calcFee(category, type, member) ;
```

Moreover the `main()` local variables `category`, `type` and `member` are not used in `main()` and are not modified by `calcFee()`, which modifies only the *copy* of these unitialised variables.  The original question states that the inputs are provided through the parameters, so you should not be accepting input within the function.  Instead `category`, `type` and `member` should be assigned values from input before calling `calcFee()`.  The question does not require you to accept user input at all, and guarantees that the input is valid (e.g. testing for lower-case is not necessary), so the following is an appropriate solution:

```
double calcFee( char category, int type, int member )
{
    double total_fee = 0 ;
    if( category == 'S' )
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                total_fee = 50.00 * member;
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                total_fee = 75.00 * member;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    else if(category == 'T')
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                total_fee = 100.00 * member;
            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {
                total_fee = 150.00 * member;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return total_fee;
}
```

The function can be greatly simplified:

```
// Pre-conditions: category = `S` or `T`
//                 type = 1 or 2
//                 member > 0
double calcFee( char category, int type, int member )
{
    double total_fee = member * 100 ;  // Primary student fee

    // Secondary staff/students pay 50% more
    if( type == 2 )
    {
        total_fee *= 1.5 ;
    }

    // Students pay half secondary/primary fee
    if( category == 'S' )
    {
        total_fee /= 2.0 ;
    }

    return total_fee ;
}
```

Note the use of comments to explain the *purpose* of the code.  I would expect your tutor to drop marks for un-commented code.

The pre-conditions indicate things that you assume to be true when the function is called so need not validate - validation is the responsibility of the calling code - otherwise in a real application you will be repeatedly validating the same data over and over rather then in only one place.

Note also the type of `member` - it makes no semantic sense to have a non-integer number of members.

Comment: Thanks man. You've helped me a lot. I'm still learning how to use it. I'll put your lesson to good use in the future

Comment: The question that I got asked me to write a function definition called calcFee() so I assume that they want the input in the function and calculate it

Comment: @MNHaris :  I would not make that assumption at all; especially if teh function signature was specified as you have it - that implies that the inputs are already known.  Moreover as a strict requirements analysis, if you are asked _only_ to perform a calculation, you should not include parameter input in the same function.  It makes the function far less useful - for example the input may come from a database of multiple members rather than being manually input every time!

Comment: noted. Can you teach me how to use bool in question b? I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: @MNHaris ; Question b is a different question; SO is not a discussion forum - you should post a new question.  Apart from anything else it will then have a large audience rather then just me.  That said the function need contain no more than `return accommodation ? 150.0 : 0 ;` - essentially if `accommodataion == true`, cost id RM150, else zero.

Comment: Now I've seen the question, it is clear that `calcFee()` _must not_ accept input; the question clearly states that the inputs are received through its parameters.

Comment: Having now seen the question, I have modified my answer.